# Diffence between usage of Ajax Update Panel and Jquery:ajax() method

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

I am little confused about Update Panel usage and usage of Jquery:Ajax() method.

Do both of them are used for Partial Post backs..

Which is the best approach to fallow?

Please help me on this..

Comment: I had the same issues and eventually decided to forget about the asp.net controls and rely on js, html, css and basic server code.

Comment: @BrettWeber I have to agree. I knew html/js and then learnt webforms. It's possible to do the same things but the whole process/lifecycle is radically different. MVC on the other hand gives you all the same capabilities without requiring such specialised knowledge - and I find it requires far less "working around" to get the results you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update panel performs a full re-render of the page, takes the section matching the panel and sends it back to the client. The browser then replaces the contents of the update panel with the new html.

jQuery's AJAX method allows you to make any request to any page and handle the response data any way you choose. This might include reading a JSON response from a web service, getting html or anything else you wish. Effectively AJAX gives you a mechanism to emulate the user browsing to a given url with GET or POST data and manipulate the results in any way you desire.

It's worth noting that the update panel is built on top of AJAX (technically Javascript's [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)) object.

There are also some gotchas with update panel, eg if you have a Captcha that is outside the panel; When the panel is updated, the captcha visible to the user doesn't change. The server generates a new page, including a new captcha. When the user submits the form, their verification code is for an old captcha.

In short, you have more control with AJAX and learning how to use it will be beneficial but depending on your use case, an update panel may do what you need for less effort.

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to SO