# Difference in using update panels and jQuery ajax() method for asynchronous request

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can you please explain difference in making ajax call using jQuery ajax() method and using update panels for asynchronous request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net components such as UpdatePanel take care of connecting the server-side code to the client-side code.

The steps for an AJAX update are something like this:

1. Hook up a click handler to a button
2. When the button is clicked, collect any data needed and send a request for the server to render some HTML
3. Replace current HTML with new HTML

The UpdatePanel takes care of those steps so you can set everything up within the .Net environment, without having to think about client-side javascript. If you have a page of moderate complexity and are doing your own AJAX, you would want to dive into the rabbit-hole that is javascript module patterns, or you could just not deal with it and use UpdatePanels if you don't care about performance.

The downside is that it adds quite a bit of javascript that you might otherwise not need.

Basically, you trade performance and flexibility for easier and more rapid development (depending on your experience with both ASP.Net and javascript). Good for "generic" intra-company pages (where rapid development often trumps usability), bad for public-facing website flashiness.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply,                               Which one will you prefer from performance point of view, Update panel or ajax() method??

Comment: @swarraj Definitely doing your own ajax. That way you can have exactly what you need and no more. I see UpdatePanel as more useful for experienced .Net coders that don't have a lot of experience with javascript or the time to learn how to do it properly, but still need / want ajax functionality on what they are working on. If you're learning, definitely learn the more flexible way :)

Comment: Also, if  you use UpdatePanel you get small side effects which are hard to get rid off, like the controls loosing focus and the prompt changing position.

Answer (score 1):

An update panel performs a re-render of the page, takes the section matching the panel and sends it back to the client. The browser then replaces the contents of the update panel with the new html.

jQuery's AJAX method allows you to make any request to any page and handle the response data any way you choose. This might include reading a JSON response from a web service, getting html or anything else you wish. Effectively AJAX gives you a mechanism to emulate the user browsing to a given url with GET or POST data and manipulate the results in any way you desire.

It's worth noting that the update panel is built on top of AJAX (technically Javascript's XMLHttpRequest) object.

In short, you have more control with AJAX and learning how to use it will be beneficial but depending on your use case, an update panel may do what you need for less effort.

stackoverflow answer [Diffence between usage of Ajax Update Panel and Jquery:ajax() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851179/diffence-between-usage-of-ajax-update-panel-and-jqueryajax-method)

Comment: Thanks a lot,Does it mean using update panels and using ajax() method for asynchronous request are not the same things??

Comment: jQuery's ajax uses XMLHttpRequest under the hood, and so does Microsoft AJAX. If you use jQuery, what you get is a convenient way to make an asynchroneous request and get the results; the specifics are up to you: what url the call goes out to, what the server needs to do, and what the client needs to handle (e.g. return the HTML to insert, or return JSON that the client parses to generate the HTML). Microsoft AJAX already made those decisions, and you have to use their way whether you need it or not. Obviously it has to handle a lot of different scenarios, and so the javascript is more bulky